# python kivy textinput text box position

Tags: python, position, kivy

I'm trying to find a way to change `Textinput` text box position and vertical size, but I can't find an example... anyone knows?
I need to change the position of the text box from the automatic position to my own.
Is there a position key like the text, size, height? And if so, how the cordinates are written?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.

You can embed the `TextInput` in another layout, position that layout and make the `TextInput` as big as the parent.